# specs2: Is there a way to use doNothing while mocking with Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, specs2

Let's say that I have a mocked trait Foo:

```
trait Foo {
  def op(x: String): Unit
}
```

and I mocked this interface using

```
val mockedFoo = mock[Foo]
```

I want the method op to throw an exception second time I call it, e.g.

```
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

trait Foo {
  def op(x: String): Unit
}

class DummySpec extends Specification with Mockito {
  "dummy" should {
    "test" in {
      val mockedFoo = mock[Foo]

      org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing().doThrow(new RuntimeException).when(mockedFoo).op(any[String])

      mockedFoo.op("This one should work fine") should not(throwAn[Exception])

      mockedFoo.op("This one should throw an exception") should throwAn[Exception]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in specs2 style? e.g.

```
mockedFoo.op(any[String]) returns Unit thenThrows new RuntimeException
```

but this doesn't compile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Unit` return type makes things a bit trickier as you can't just chain:

```
returns "foo" thenThrows new RuntimeException
```

But you can still solve this problem if you use `answers` like below:

```
mockedFoo.op(anyString) answers {args => } thenThrows new RuntimeException
```

See if this works for you.